# Firebase: server response does not contain a JSON object

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-oauth

I am trying to run a ASP.NET Core API to send FCM push notifications.

The API works with Firebase SDK. The code is basically the one in the documentation:

Initialize the default app, configPath being the JSON project configuration

```
FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
                    {
                        Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(configPath), //JSON con API Key credentials
                        
                    });
```

Example of the payload I am sending

```
//Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
                //registration token.
                //var message = new Message()
                //{
                //    Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                //    {
                //        { "score", "850" },
                //        { "time", "2:45" },
                //    },
                //    Token = registrationToken,
                //    Notification = new Notification
                //    {
                //        Body = "Test"
                //    }
                //};
```

The async task I am sending

```
string response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(payload).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Everything works OK on local (push notifications are being send), configuration seems to be alright but the deployed API running on my server returns the following error:

[image]

Server runs on Windows 10, has internet connectivity and already has other APIs (not FCM related) working fine.

As a ServiceUnavailable error I have already checked if its a Firebase problem but then again if it is Firebase problem it wouldn't work on local, right?

Comment: Couple of quick options you could try is, check that the file declared as configPath is copied in the build output, check your server firewall is configured for outgoing http traffic, it may be that the traffic needs to route through a proxy if your in a corporate environment.

Comment: Not a solution but a couple things to check/be aware of.  First, the response not containing JSON just typically means the request failed and you got something that isn't JSON back, typically some HTML explaining what's wrong.  Second, ServiceUnavailable is a 503 error which is a server side error which means on the Google side.  I'd double check URLs and credentials and see if you can get the console to show the HTML response from the (Google) server which may have more details.